# AccessViolationException in EmguCV(3.x) while capturing

Tags: c#, emgucv, access-violation

I'm programming in C#(WindowsForm). I want to use EmguCV(3.1) to capture an .avi file. When I load a file I see this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

After this exception I see this window:

[image]

Here is my code to load a file:

```
private void LoadVideoFromFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();
    d.ShowDialog();

    _capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture(d.FileName);
    _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
}
```

And here is my code for showing avi file:

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{            
    Action a = () =>
        {
            UMat captured = new UMat();
            Boolean cap = _capture.Retrieve(captured);

            pictureBox1.Image = captured.Bitmap;
        };

    pictureBox1.Invoke(a);
}
```

Comment: Are you running it in debug mode, have you tried release?

Comment: Yes, I'm running in debug but what is the problem? what is difference between debug and release?

Comment: Try to disable edit and continue feature https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164926.aspx

Comment: No, no thing happened when I release. I still see that error

Comment: It seems that this is a race condition! I will try to fix this using mutex. I will publish my answer, if this problem be fixed using mutex.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I threw together a little program to see what was going on. Mind you I am not a WinForms kinda cat. I am using EmguCV v3.1 x64, compiled for x64 and using .NET 4.6.1`    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        VideoCapture _capture;
        bool run = true;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();
        d.ShowDialog();

        tbxFileName.Text = d.FileName;
        tbxFileName.Refresh();
        _capture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(d.FileName);
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
        double fps = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
        double frameCount = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount);

        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        int currentFrame = 1;

        while(run)
        {
            if (!_capture.Grab())
                run = false;

            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32((++currentFrame / frameCount) * 100);

            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(1000.0 / fps));

            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Action a = () =>
        {
            UMat captured = new UMat();
            Boolean cap = _capture.Retrieve(captured);

            pictureBox1.Image = captured.Bitmap;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        };

        pictureBox1.Invoke(a);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

`
The only error I received is when I forgot to copy cvextern.dll and its other dependents to the bin folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UMat which uses OpenCL if it is available. Most of the time when I hit things like this it is because I forgot to compile for x64. Try that and see if it helps.